# Paginas en tablas

Tags: php, html

Cómo puede hacer que esta tabla cuando se vaya llenando muestre por "página" 10 líneas, y que cuando pase esas 10 líneas, se tengan que hacer otra página, y poner un buscador.

Me cuesta hacer todo esto porque soy nuevo, y estoy intentando aprender.

[image: Original]

Y pasaría a ser esto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código actual:

```html
<?php
 require('conexion.php');
 
 $query="SELECT *  FROM umg511_tbl";

 $resultado=$mysqli->query($query);
 
?>
<html>
 <head>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,300italic,400italic,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" charset=UTF-8>
  <title>En Desarrollo</title>
 </head>
    <body>
 
  <ul>
   <li class="imagenes"><a href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.png" class="imagenes" /></a></li>
   <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="ip.php">Direccion</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Datos</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="datos">
  
  <table>
 <thead>
  <tr class="centro">
   <td>ID</td>
   <td>Dia</td>
   <td>Descargar</td>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
     <?php while($row=$resultado->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
      <tr>
       <td name="id">
        <center> <?php echo $row['umg511_id']; ?> </center>
       </td>
       <td name="fecha">
        <center><?php echo $row['umg511_day'];?></center>
       </td>
       <td name="descargar">
        <form action="export.php" method="post" id="enviar">
         <input name="idOculto" id="idOculto" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['umg511_id']; ?>" />
         <center><input type="submit" value="Descargar" /></center>
        </form>
       </td>
      </tr>
     <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table> 

  
  </div>
  <div class="copy">
   <a>©Created only for ...</a>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

---

Y si añades muchas entradas, pasa esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El truco esta en usar la cláusula LIMIT de MySql, ejemplo:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 3")
```

Esta opción te permite obtener solo los primeros 3 registros, luego:

```
$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 0, 10")
```

Te permite obtener 10 registros desde el registro 0 ¿Vas pillando el truco?.

Ahora con una variable:

```
$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table LIMIT $startrow, 10")
```

donde `$stratrow` debería ir aumentando en 10 en cada click en "siguiente pagina" así iras sacando los primeros 10 registros, luego los siguientes 10 y así puedes ir paginando tus resultados.

FUENTE: http://www.phpsimplicity.com/tips.php?id=1

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Tengo una duda, esas variables "$fetch" donde tendria que añadirlas? Saludos.

Comment: Tal y como lo usas tu

$resultado=$mysqli->query($query);

solo asignale a $query = "SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 3" y prueva el resultado

Comment: Vale, ya lo tengo. Gracias. Ahora solo falta lo de "hacer varias paginas" y el buscador.

Comment: @PepeFlanco claro como te mencione solo es aumentar el contador con el botón siguiente, normalmente esto se hace con un post . Si mi respuesta soluciono tu pregunta recuerda que debes seleccionarla.

Comment: Vale, ahora lo comprendo. Saludos y cerrado :D (Cerrar es solo darle al tick, verdad? Soy nuevo aqui xD)

Comment: @PepeFlanco acá no se cierra nada pero con el tick escojes la respuesta correcta con eso basta

Comment: Oky, muchas gracias.